# How to stop graph from appearing in extra quadrants

Tags: radicals

I was simplifying the equation, $\sqrt{(x^2 + x)}xy = 5$, to, $\sqrt{(x^4 y^2 + x^3 y^2)} = 5$, using $\sqrt{(x)} x = \sqrt{(x^3)}$ but the graph appeared in all quadrants not just two and four. Can anyone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It is $$ab\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\ne \sqrt{a^2b^2(a^2+b^2)}$$ since we have $$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$$

Comment: Then is there any way to simplify explain $\sqrt{x^2+x}xy$ down further

Comment: Only when you assume that $$xy\geq 0$$ then we get $$\sqrt{x^2+x}xy=\sqrt{x^2y^2(x^2+x)}$$

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner $xy$ is positif, otherwise LHS would not be equal to 5.